# Open Source for non-ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and ARC Users

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

We have some open source libraries that are distributed via code into other projects via git modules with Xcode. Some of the projects would remain with explicit retains/release while other projects would like to leverage Automatic Reference Counting. Is there anyway for the same source to be compilable in Xcode projects with and without ARC? Would it work if it was compiled into a static library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bundle a project that compiles your open source library as a static library, and the other projects link against your static library instead of compiling the source directly, then that would work. The other projects can embed your library's project file if they want, so that your library will get compiled before theirs, or you can just distribute the static library pre-compiled.

Comment: You might find this useful, it's a step by step guide to converting ARC and includes instructions for selectively enabling/disabling ARC in files ... http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained

Comment: The one tricky part with distributing static libraries that were compiled with ARC is that you need to include libarclite_iphoneos.a (for iOS) in any non-ARC application which uses this library and wants to target iOS 4.x.  This Apple Developer Forums thread has a little more discussion about this: https://devforums.apple.com/message/533729